# accept only allowed characters EditText. using Regex and inputfilter kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can i use edit text to accept only characters and numbers and space using regex and input filter

Answer (score 0):

for text use this in your xml

```
android:inputType="text"
```

for numbers :

```
android:inputType="number"
```

and for text with spaces `android:inputType="text"` this will handle everything!

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
   <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:digits=" ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"
      android:inputType="text"
   />
```